# Convert date format from selected results

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

SQL Noob here and can't seem to wrap my head around this.

We have results in our database which is displayed at the MM/DD/YYYY format.

However it gets recorded in the american date format when someone has it set on their PC. For example we have results for the future (08/12/2017) Which to us is the 8th December but it should be the 12th Of August.

I've selected results in a query and want to swap the MM / DD so the 08 and the 12 swap places. Is this possible?

Comment: You should be storing dates using the native `date` type in your database, not as strings.  You should fix the data.

Comment: I wish I could but I don't have any access. Our programmers are stuck in their ways and i'm just trying to automate the tedious process of fixing the problem is causes.

Comment: First tag your DBMS, then we'll tell you that dates are not store in any "format", only displayed as such, unless some muppet has used varchar. Each DBMS has a different way of displaying a formatted date, so tag it.

Comment: If you use proper DATE type columns, you will never have to face this issue. Stop storing presentation, and store data instead. You can display it however you like in your UI.

Comment: What kind of database? (Oracle, MS Sql Server, MySql, Teradata, ...) Unless the table stores it as a DATE and it supports [FORMAT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_format.asp) the answer will depend on it.

Comment: It's a PostgreSQL database

Comment: What is the data type of the field that contains the date? (date, timestamp, varchar, char, ...)

Comment: It's currently set to date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If stored as date and you want to format to real world/non-USA format on display:

```
select to_char(TheDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY') as FormattedDate
```

and for if it's stored as text:

```
select to_char(to_date(TheDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'DD/MM/YYYY') as FormattedDate
```